# Who is Professor Stein?

Tags: dc, the-new-52, batgirl

In Batgirl #2 (Oct 2011), there is some graffiti written on the back of a train. It said,"PROFESSOR STEIN IS ALIVE"

> [image]

Who is Professor Stein?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Professor Stein is the creator of the Firestorm matrix, and for portions of the old DC continuity, he was one half of Firestorm.  Firestorm is a hero formed when 2 specific people combine, with one of them having physical control of Firestorm, and the other sharing Firestorm's mind.  This means the two of them are able to communicate with each other via thought, while the one with physical control of Firestorm is able to talk to others.

The specific graffiti you're asking about is foreshadowing that Professor Stein is alive in the new continuity, where apparently he's assumed to be dead.

---

I thought it was suggesting that Firestorm is coming to the new DCU.  However, a new comic, [*The Fury of Firestorm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firestorm_%28comics%29#Publication_history), is already out, and it was written by Gail Simone and Ethan Van Sciver with Yıldıray Çınar providing the art. Per the comment below, I was incorrect, as he's already present.

Comment: I thought it already came out. I read the first issue a few weeks ago. I didn't see any correlation between the two comics tho.

Answer (score 2):

**Professor Stein is Alive**

**History:**

Professor Martin Stein was part of the original character Firestorm, the Nuclear Man. In this series, Firestorm was a superhero who could reorder the atomic and molecular structure of anything non-living. He also possessed the power of flight and could project concussive blasts of force from his hands. The original Firestorm was distinguished by his integrated dual identity. High school student Ronnie Raymond and Nobel Prize-winning physicist Martin Stein were caught in a nuclear accident that allowed them to fuse into the "nuclear man" Firestorm. Due to Stein's being unconscious during the accident, Raymond was prominently in command of the Firestorm form with Stein a voice of reason inside his mind. Ronnie was later killed and resurrected at the end of the Darkest Night/Brightest Day Green Lantern Saga.

In a strange derailment of comic characters, John Ostrander decided to take Firestorm the Nuclear Man in a completely different direction and by Firestorm the Nuclear Man vol. 2 #100, Martin Stein learned that he was destined to be a fire elemental being during the incident that created the Nuclear Man persona. He would have become a true fire elemental and would have been were it not for Ronnie Raymond also being there by circumstance.

Raymond and Mikhail Arkadin (who was part of the fire elemental being) were returned to their old lives, and Stein, now the elemental entity Firestorm, was accidentally exiled to deep space in the process of saving the Earth. He thereafter spent many years traveling through space as a wanderer, returning to earth on only two occasions: the War of the Gods crossover event, and again in Extreme Justice #5, where Stein cured Raymond of his leukemia and allowed Raymond to retain the original Firestorm persona on his own. Stein perished at the hands of Deathstorm in Brightest Day.

---

**Suppositions:**

All of that history exists before the hard reboot of the DCnU and personally I would not pay it any more attention than its appearance on the back of a train as graffiti. If it is a clue, it would be a strange place for it and a very subtle one at that. The DCnU has not had an appearance of Professor Stein since the release of the new volume The Fury of Firestorm number 3, at the time of this writing.

Comment: The question was Who was Professor Stein. I answered the question. In the DCnU, we do not know who he will be. And even with the release of the Fury of Firestorm, we have not seen him, yet. Your downvote was premature since the actual question was answered in the first sentence: "Professor Martin Stein was part of the original character Firestorm, the Nuclear Man. In this series, Firestorm was a superhero who could reorder the atomic and molecular structure of anything non-living."

Comment: Your edit corrects the issue I had. +1.